# How to pass dataset through query

Tags: c#

I  need to get a database values to the p_cat combo box .....but i cannot pass the dataset inside the query..

```
class Datatbl_Class1
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    public DataSet filldata(string q)
    {
        string myconnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username = root; password = 12345V";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(myconnection);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(q, con);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
}
```

---

```
Select_int_Class1 s4 = new Select_int_Class1();
string q = "SELECT Sup_ID FROM gtec_computer.supplier WHERE Sup_Name='" +p_cmb_sup.Text+ "'";

string ww = "Sup_ID";
int t = s4.select_val_int(q, ww);

DataSet n = new DataSet();
Datatbl_Class1 dt = new Datatbl_Class1();

string Query = "SELECT  Cat_ID FROM gtec_computer.supplier_detail WHERE Sup_Id="+t+" ";
n = dt.filldata(Query)
```

---

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string myconnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username = root; password = 12345V";

MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(myconnection);
string q1 = "SELECT  cat_Name FROM gtec_computer.category WHERE Cat_ID= " + n + " ";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(q1, con);
MySqlDataAdapter da1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da1.Fill(ds);
p_cat.DataSource = ds;
```

Comment: Consider using the html tag <hr> it is much cleaner and faster than `.......`. Ahh, now that's betta!

Comment: You don't need to use `<hr>`, just a couple of dashes `---`. We have help on formatting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). cc @C.Lang

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to via parameter to the function call in the class... However, by building your command strings, you would be wide open for SQL-injection.  Look into parameterized queries.  Now, back to your original code and an alternative implementation...

```
class Datatbl_Class1
{
    public DataSet filldata(string q )
    {
        string myconnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username = root; password = 12345V";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(myconnection);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(q, con);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ReturnThisOne = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ReturnThisOne);
        return ReturnThisOne;
    }
}
```

Just dont make the "ds" as a property of the class.  Just create a new instance of a dataset within your method.  It will be a pointer anyhow.  Fill that and return the pointer to the calling source as you already are doing with your "n = dt.filldata(Query)".  Yes, the function is no longer using the data table, but since it's reference is being returned, then the "n" location that is calling it will retain it.  It won't get released to garbage collection until the function that "n" is in gets released.

Again, look into parameters to prevent sql-injection.  But this should get you going.